# infinite integration with matlab

Tags: matlab, math, integral

I want to compute the following type of integrals in Matlab.

[image: \int _{0}^\infty e^{-(u*u)} du]

It is the integral of function e^-(u)*u and the boundaries are zero and infinity. This integral should return 1.

How can I do this in Matlab?

Comment: The integrand that you show in the formula is e^(-u*u), not e^(-u)*u. You should edit the formula in the question

Answer (score 5):

And if you don't have the symbolic toolbox, or want more speed, `quadgk` supports infinite limits:

```
f = @(x) x.*exp(-x);
a = quadgk(f, 0, inf) 

a =
    1.000000000000000e+00
```

Answer (score 2):

[Symbolic toolbox.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/int.html)

```
syms u
int(exp(-u)*u, u, 0, inf)
```