# How to fix the weird result of integral?

Tags: matlab, integral

I want to compute integral(@(v)v^46*exp(-v^2),0,inf). Mathematically, it can be computed. However, when I run in matlab, it gives NaN. Is it a problem due to the precision of the computer? If yes, how can I fix it? I also try of changing inf to a big no, say from 10000,100000,1000000,... the values increase and then drop to a very small no close to 0.

In the extreme case, I need to compute integral(@(v)(v-a)^200*exp(-v^2),0,inf), so I admire any correction based on the last integral.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying problem is that isn't possible to integrate to infinity by substituting the floating point `inf` number. The `integral` function is purely numeric.

> q = integral(fun,xmin,xmax) numerically integrates function fun from
>   xmin to xmax using global adaptive quadrature and default error
>   tolerances.

You will need to use the symbolic toolbox, which manipulates symbol rather than floating point values [as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839394/infinite-integration-with-matlab).

Comment: If you think that that answer solves the question, please flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: @Adriaan I don't think its a duplicate because OP is using the wrong function, and has confused numeric integration with symbol manipulation. Possibly missing the `syms` command.

Comment: The one I suggest may have explicit result. How about integral(@(v)(v-a)^200*exp(-v^2),0,inf)? When using symbolic, how can I do it? It may not have explicit formula. Using the symbolic toolbox does not help.

Comment: @will_cheuk you need to use the `int` command

Comment: I have tried. see below:
syms u
int(exp(-u*u)*(u-10)^46, u, 0, inf)
 
ans =
 
int(exp(-u^2)*(u - 10)^46, u, 0, Inf)

Comment: Also, I have read the documentation for integral, the xmin and xmax can be infinity.